# Mastering Sudoku?

Tags: sudoku

I have been solving sudoku for years but this one is the hardest of all that I have ever completed. It took me 2 weeks to complete it. Here it is TRY AND SOLVE:[image]

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought posting questions like this is discouraged on Puzzling.SE?

Comment: Are there multiple solutions?

Comment: Well, it will only take me a minute or two to solve.

**1.** Open New Tab.
**2.** Search "Sudoku Solver"
**3.** Click on a page.
**4.** Enter the numbers.
**5.** Press solve.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole No.  It won't take you a minute or two.  Most solvers actually can't solve this one.  See the duplicate.

Comment: You can try to solve this puzzle on this website: http://asudoku.com/#800000000003600000070090200050007000000045700000100030001000068008500010090000400